# how to show unique data using sqlite database in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created database in SQLiteOpenHelper class. I've also done insertion in database in `Button click` event in other activity(`InsertActivity.java`). Now, when i display data on listview then two same entry generated. How to display distinct record in `listview`?

**ListActivity.java**

```
public class ListActivity extends Activity {
    ListView lv;
    ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> items_id = new ArrayList<String>();
    dbhelper dh;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    int index_id;
    Button btn;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
        Button btn;
        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.newProjectlist);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                    Intent intent= new Intent(ListActivity.this,NewProject.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });  
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.projectListView);
        setUpList();
        dh = new dbhelper(this);

        Cursor c = getAllData();
        showAllData(c);  
        registerForContextMenu(lv);      
    }

  @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

        if(v.getId() == R.id.projectList){
            menu.setHeaderIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            menu.setHeaderTitle("Record List");
            menu.add(0,1,menu.NONE,"Delete Record");
            menu.add(0,2,menu.NONE,"Show Record");
        }
    }

    @Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int itemId = item.getItemId();
        if(itemId == 1)
        {
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo menuinfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
            int poistion = menuinfo.position;
            String id_string = items_id.get(poistion);
            long id = Long.valueOf(id_string);

            //menuinfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
            //index_id = menuinfo.position;
            deleteUserData(index_id);
            items_id.remove(poistion);
        }
        if(itemId == 2){
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo menuinfo;
            menuinfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
            index_id = menuinfo.position;
            editUserData(index_id);
        }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}

    private void editUserData(int indexid) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String user_id = items_id.get(indexid);
        Intent intEdit = new Intent(ListActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        intEdit.putExtra("EditID", user_id);
        startActivityForResult(intEdit, 1);
    }

    private void deleteUserData(int indexid) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      String user_id = items_id.get(indexid);
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "id " + user_id, 1).show();
        db = dh.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete("timer","_ID" + "=" + indexid, null);
        finish();
//      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Record deleted successfully", 1).show();
    }

    private void showAllData(Cursor c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while(c.moveToNext())
        {
            int id = c.getInt(0);
            String name = c.getString(1);
            String timerpoint1 = c.getString(2);
            String timerpoint2 = c.getString(3);
            String timerpoint3 = c.getString(4);
            String servicetime1 = c.getString(5);
            String servicetime2 = c.getString(6);
            items.add("" + name);
            items_id.add(""+id);
        }
        setUpList();
    }

    private Cursor getAllData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db = dh.getReadableDatabase();
        //String sortorder = dh.Name + "DESC";
    //  String query ="SELECT DISTINCT name FROM timer";
    //  Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    //   if (c != null) {
    //            c.moveToFirst();
    //        }
//      String[] cols = new String[] {"name"};
        Cursor c = db.query(true, "timer",null,null,null,null,null,null,null);   
        //Cursor cur = db.query(Distinct,"timer", null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        startManagingCursor(c);
    //  Cursor c=db.rawQuery("select distinct Name from timer;",null);
        return c;   
        }     
    private void setUpList() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items));
    }   

    }
```

Comment: I think you can just `DISTINCT` in your query to get distinct record

Comment: please give me a code for that HERO..

Comment: .. Really, you expected an answer in 7 minutes? I have to wonder what you do with yourself when you order pizza. That aside, there is no "please give me a code for that" here; perhaps start with taking a look on Google for SQL's `DISTINCT` keyword?

Comment: HERO, u suggest for DISTINCT, I already try it. Please give me some other suggestion for "How to make Distinct record in sqlite using android".

Comment: Eric , If you are good programmer then u never excuse but do the work silentely.

Comment: ... I don't think I'm the only one that has no idea what you just said.

Comment: If you have no idea for my questions than please silent. I tried hard for getting answer. I create display query in different manner but i m not reach the goal. So i need code. Understand??

Answer (score 0):

Try with `GROUP BY`. If you still don't find the desired result, check whether you have gone wrong in executing sqlite queries anywhere and let me know.

```
SELECT Name 
FROM timer
GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: OMG! I haven't seen it. What did you just do with ListActivity. You are coding this "public class ListActivity extends Activity". Can you tell me on what purpose you are defining your class with the predefined name "ListActivity"

Comment: i found my problem. Thanx dude.

Answer (score 0):

**How to Avoid Repeat entry in ListView???**

avoid use of addRecord method() repeatly. Because when you call insert() in addRecord() then just one time define addRecord() in onClick() and finally you avoid same record entry in Listview.